# В каких случаях следует применять pre-compiled headers ?

Tags: c, c++

В каких случаях следует применять pre-compiled headers ? Можете объяснить на пальцах и с каким-нибудь примером. Почитал в вики, в принципе всё понятно. Только когда их нужно применять в реальных проектах, а когда не нужно, я не понял :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чем больше проект - тем это нужнее. Всё, что изменится - время компиляции. Применяйте - хуже не будет. Может быть, это не имеет смысла только в очень маленьких программах.

Т.к. это опция компилятора, а не расширение языка, компилировать чем-то ещё проект она не помешает.

Answer (score 2):

Применять нужно всегда, когда критично время компиляции. Если проект велик, а ресурсы рабочей станции ограничены, то время сборки большого проекта может растягиваться на десятки минут. Что достаточно сильно затрудняет цикл отладки: исправление, сборка, выполнение, проверка. А если сборка целого проекта занимает секунды, то и без заранее скомпилированных заголовков вполне можно обойтись.